# Child component is not rendered while using NgFor in Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a parent component which has some child component like this

Parent html

```
<app-select\>

<app-custom-select *ngFor ="Let item of searcheditem" 
    [value]="item"></app-custom-select>
</app-select>
```

app-custom-select -child html

```
<div *ngIf="type != '3

<p>{title}</p>

</div>
```

When i right the unit test case for pareocknt ts

```
const msearcheditem: searchedModel[] = [{ title: "testsearcg",category: "0",url:"",description: "",rating:Rating.NA }, { title: "test reports",category: "0",url:"",description: "",rating:Rating.NA }];
      
      component.recentSearches=mockRecentSearchesList;
      fixture.detectChanges(); 
      flush();
      component.isFocussedState=true; 
      component.isActiveTypedState =false; 
      fixture.detectChanges();       

      fixture.whenStable().then(()=>{
        fixture.detectChanges();
        console.log(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement);
        console.log(component.recentSearches);
        const element: DebugElement[]=fixture.query(By.css('app-custom-select'))
        expect(element.length).toEqual(2); -- Error and the element 

When i printed the DOM element it shows like this <!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": ""
}-->

Not sure whats going on any help ? appreciated
```

using flush and fakeasync

Comment: there're several errors in your code -I imagine it's when you try to ask the question- Please edit the question and write the correct code (e.g. is `let`not `Let`, the `*ngFor`must belong to the div,...)

Comment: Thanks i had edited my code . I am assigning the values but its not been binded